# making an endpoint in turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm making a maze with turtle graphics for a class project and I have one more main thing to complete before I'm finished...

I've created a second "turtle" to make a box at the endpoint. So the objective is to finish the maze and get the turtle in the box. But I am unsure how to make the box an actual endpoint and have a message pop up.

Here is my code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

screen.setup(650, 850)
screen.title("Turtle Keys")
screen.bgpic('scooby_doo_maze.gif')

move = Turtle(shape="triangle")
move.penup()
move.setx(-150)
move.sety(200)
move.pendown()
move.pensize(5)

box = Turtle(shape="square")
box.hideturtle()
box.speed(0)
box.penup()
box.setx(150)
box.sety(-190)
box.pendown()
box.right(90)
box.forward(100)
box.right(90)
box.forward(100)
box.right(90)
box.forward(100)
box.right(90)
box.forward(100)

def keyUp():
    move.forward(12)

def keyLeft():
    move.left(90)

def keyRight():
    move.right(90)

def keyDown():
    move.backward(12)

def keyReset():
    move.reset()
    move.penup()
    move.setx(-150)
    move.sety(200)
    move.pendown()
    move.pensize(5)

screen.onkey(keyUp, "Up")
screen.onkey(keyLeft, "Left")
screen.onkey(keyRight, "Right")
screen.onkey(keyDown, "Down")
screen.onkey(keyReset, "r")

screen.listen()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.  Specifically, remove the overhead code (especially the user-control routines), append your best attempt, and show what it *does* accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

We just need to add few features.  First, instead of drawing the end point with turtle `box`, we make turtle `box` the endpoint by expanding the turtle itself via `box.shapesize()`.  This way, we can use `move.distance(box)` to determine if `move` is near the center of `box`.

Second, we need a function called by all the movement functions to test if above distance is close enough and then invoke the following:

Third, we introduce `screen.textinput()` to let the play know they've succeeded and offer then the option to play again, or quit.  I've reworked your code below to introduce these additions and tweak it a bit for style:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(650, 850)
screen.title("Turtle Keys")
screen.bgpic('scooby_doo_maze.gif')

def insideBox():
    if move.distance(box) < 60:
        play_again = screen.textinput("Success!", "Play again?")

        if play_again and play_again.lower().startswith('y'):
            keyReset()
        else:
            screen.bye()

def keyUp():
    move.forward(12)
    insideBox()

def keyLeft():
    move.left(90)

def keyRight():
    move.right(90)

def keyDown():
    move.backward(12)
    insideBox()

def keyReset():
    move.reset()
    move.penup()
    move.goto(-150, 200)
    move.pendown()
    move.pensize(5)
    screen.listen()  # it's here because screen.textinput() unsets it

screen.onkey(keyUp, "Up")
screen.onkey(keyLeft, "Left")
screen.onkey(keyRight, "Right")
screen.onkey(keyDown, "Down")
screen.onkey(keyReset, "r")

move = Turtle(shape="triangle")
keyReset()

box = Turtle(shape="square")
box.color("black", "white")
box.shapesize(5, 5, 5)
box.penup()
box.goto(150, -190)

screen.mainloop()
```

This is a situation where I would avoid `screen.exitonclick()` as you need to click the window to get it to listen and easily end up closing it!  Using `screen.mainloop()` should be sufficient and let the user close the window by not choosing to play again or using the window controls.